# Android BitmapFactory.decodeFile() method returns null

Tags: android, bitmap

I am facing an issue with Bitmap object creation.

When i call the BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFullPath) it returns null.I tried with the available solutions like giving complete image path.But I didn't get the solution.

Can any one please tell me  why it is returning null.?

According to the **Developer docs BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFullPath) will return null if the path is not available or if unable to decode**.

In my case I am facing this because of Second one(Unable to Decode).

So Please anyone tell me How can I avoid this.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try providing a valid bitmap?

Comment: Show your code please and also mention which version you are using.